# How to delete a field in elasticsearch 2.3.0? I am using sense to do my queries

Tags: elasticsearch

I have inserted a new field `wiki_collection` and set its value to `true` in my document by using:

```
POST /pibtest1/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.wiki_collection=true"
  },
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "url":"http%3A%2F%2Fwww.searchtechnologies.com%2Fbundles%2Fmodernizr%3Fv%3D7-yR01kdRVQ7W1RQzMBVKYLDhCt0itEATWHixfzE8Os1"
    }
  }
}
```

But now I want to delete this field. I am trying to do this:

```
POST /pibtest1/_update
{
    "script" : "ctx._source.remove(\"wiki_collection\")"
}
```

But I am getting an error which says:

```
{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "invalid_type_name_exception",
            "reason": "Document mapping type name can't start with '_'"
         }
      ],
      "type": "invalid_type_name_exception",
      "reason": "Document mapping type name can't start with '_'"
   },
   "status": 400
}
```

Is there any other way to delete a field in elasticsearch?

Edit: I have updated by query:

```
POST /pibtest1/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.remove(\"wiki_collection\")"
  },
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "url": "http://www.searchtechnologies.com/bundles/modernizr?v=7-yR01kdRVQ7W1RQzMBVKYLDhCt0itEATWHixfzE8Os1"
    }
  }
}
```

But now I am getting a new filed called "remove='wiki_collection'" in my documents which looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvxIa.png
I want to remove/delete this wiki_collection field from my documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your update is wrong. It should either be (you specify the **complete path - index/type/ID**):

```
POST /pibtest1/test/234/_update
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.remove(\"wiki_collection\")"
  }
}
```

Or you use the same **`_update_by_query`**:

```
POST /pibtest1/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.remove(\"wiki_collection\")"
  },
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "url": "whatever"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please check my updated post. I followed your second solution. But now I am getting a new field called remove='wiki_collection' in my documents. I want to delete this field from my document.

Comment: How do  you run the REST commands? Sense, curl, something else?

Comment: I am using SENSE to run my queries

Comment: I used the same. This is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/astefan/c63d206f1c715abf7c94b2f19dbded0c) with my complete test.

Comment: Appreciate your help. I will take a look at your solution.